# Customize Video view in iOS 3.0

Tags: objective-c, xcode, video

I need help, how add customize video view in iOS 3.0! I use MPMoviePlayerController, but method (view) use in iOS 3.2, not earlier. I understand that the old version, but there is a need to support in iOS 3.0. Or exist any alternatives this realization.

Comment: There is no good way to do it in iOS 3.0

Comment: As Jason Coco says, there was no video API available prior to iOS 3.2.  I would also question the need to support iOS 3.0, somewhere around 90% iOS users are on iOS 5+ so unless you are specifically targeting legacy devices, even support for iOS 3.2 isn't so important now.

Comment: I'm very-very understand you =)  but my app need support iOS 3.0 - 5.1, I sit and cry myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem as follows. With iOS 3.0 to 3.2, I show the player by default, and with the iOS 3.2 shows customize MPMoviePlayerController.